# How to leave my general "Routes" intact when operating code in a specific "Area" with its own "Routes"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using using MVC3 with C#.

I have a sub application within an area, while the main application hangs off the root of the project
ie:

```
Root
  - Controller
  - Models
  - Views
  - Areas
     - SubApp
```

The SubApp has its own routing file with the following default route:

```
            context.MapRoute(
            "SubApp_default",
            "SubApp/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have a generic menu with URLs that should point to the root Controller/Actions. However when I am in the SubApp these Menu URLs get changed,for example, to :

```
/SubApp/Home/Index
```

When it should be:

```
/Home/Index
```

I suspect it is the above "SubApp_default" route that is causing the issue. I want "Root" urls to use the "Root" routing if you get my drift, and only area specific URLs to use the area routing.

Thoughts please.

Many thanks.

EDIT1:

I am using ActionLinks ie :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create Order", "Index", "Order", new { area=""},null)
```

which would appear as a menu item. When in the SubApp area/application this gets routed as

```
 /SubApp/Order/Index
```

rather than

```
/Order/Index.
```

I have this menu ActionLink code in the _layout page.

Comment: Do I have to specify "{area=..." in all my ActionLinks. I hope not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have areas in your app you will need to be specific about which controllers and actions you want to point to.

If you are inside your SubApp area, then any link you need to create pointing to the root, should include an empty area.

```
@Url.Action("index", "home", new { area = "" }
```

Using the same concept, any url from the root controllers to the SubApp area should include the area in the link:

```
@Url.Action("index", "home", new { area = "SubApp" }
```

If you are not crossing any boundaries, then not specifying the area will default to the area you are in.

Comment: Ok, found out that it was not working due to the use of an area specific _layout, stored within the area. Now using Root _layout. I am a little surprised that there is no method to resolve this within the routing files rather than having to specify an area attribute for each actionlink?